# click next previous button wd calendar append duplicate values

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am using the [jQuery calender plugin](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php).

The problem is that whenever I try to refresh data by clicking on refresh button it gives me duplicate values.

my jQuery:

```
 //previous date range
            $("#sfprevbtn").click(function(e) {

                var p = $("#gridcontainer").previousRange().BcalGetOp();
                if (p && p.datestrshow) {
                     $("#gridcontainer").reload();
                    $("#txtdatetimeshow").text(p.datestrshow);

                }

            });
            //next date range
            $("#sfnextbtn").click(function(e) {
                var p = $("#gridcontainer").nextRange().BcalGetOp();
                if (p && p.datestrshow) {

                    $("#txtdatetimeshow").text(p.datestrshow);
                }

            });
```

Comment: Make sure to `clear` your calendar data first before appending the new data.

Comment: any idea to clear data

Comment: Check the documentation, it should be in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear your calendar data first before appending the new data. Try the following code:

`$("#gridcontainer").empty();`

You can find documentation for the wdCalendar plugin here: [Documentation](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/docs/)

Comment: hei friend i tried this , but dont know exactly where to use this

Comment: Right before `reload()`

Comment: $("#showreflashbtn").click(function(e){
$("#gridcontainer").empty();
$("#gridcontainer").reload();
$('.filterevents').removeClass('fcurrent');

}); is it correct ?

Comment: @DhanushBala if it works for you, yes.

Comment: not clearing data same issue happening again

Comment: @DhanushBala I thought it worked before? Did it suddenly stop working?

Comment: dont know bro but its not working now ,

Comment: @DhanushBala I'm not magical, I can't smell what's wrong. If it worked before and now stopped working, that means you changed something which made it stop working.

Comment: empty() clear the calendar , but again it appends with duplicates

Comment: @DhanushBala Are you perhaps appending / reloading twice?